# CS1617 error message when building MonoDevelop 7.6 with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows, monodevelop

I have an error message when building under Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 Team explorer.

"CSC : error CS1617: Option non valide '8.0' pour /langversion. Utilisez '/langversion:?' pour lister les valeurs prises en charge."

I use the winbuild bat file. I tried to build from VS also. I followed the instructions on the page https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/

Comment: You probably don't want to waste your time, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b If you insist, you might learn from https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop-windows

Comment: Okay, so far I wonder why the page is stil online and not updated or deleted ? Then, said that, which tool can I use to develop .Net Core apps ?

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/tools it cannot be clearer.